# How can I speed up a selective deep copy command in unix?

Tags: command-line, unix, performance, find

I am (ab?)using the unix 'find' command to recursively export files from a directory tree that is littered with .svn directories. This command takes a long time to run. Is there a faster way to accomplish the same thing?

```
find source/ -type f -and ! -path '*.svn*' -and -exec cp {} export \;
```

What I want to do is search every subdirectory in the directory tree starting at `source/`, and copy any files in those directories to the `export` directory, skipping any files that are in the .svn directories

---

**Update:** (complete solution, based on the [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/345889/how-can-i-speed-up-a-selective-deep-copy-command-in-unix/345918#345918) posted by [Michał Šrajer](https://superuser.com/users/76747/michal-srajer)):

```
find source/ -type f -and ! -path '*.svn*' -and -print0 | xargs -0 \
    cp --target-directory=export
```

For those who are curious: [xargs](https://superuser.com/questions/345889/how-can-i-speed-up-a-selective-deep-copy-command-in-unix/345918#345918) on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot use `rsync` as jhcaiced answered (+1), you can do it in several ways:

1. copy directory with one `cp -r` and then remove all .svn dirs using `find . -name .svn` -delete`
2. pipe one `tar c` to another `tar x`. Tar has `--exclude=`

You can also optimize your code. Note that you call `cp` for each file. This takes long time. You can use `-print0` and `xargs -0`. This will be much faster.

Comment: Your suggestion to use `-print0` and `xargs -0` worked beautifully. Thank you!

Comment: @e.James: you welcome

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid copying the same files over and over using rsync, the command would be something like:

rsync source/ export/ --exclude '*.svn'

If you need to also remove from export the files removed from source/ then add the --delete parameter to the command.

Comment: +1, but will that preserve the directory structure? I'm trying *not* to preserve that structure. i.e. `export` should contain no subdirectories, just a big list of files